# Comparing a wrapped function whether it is instance of a decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I have `decorator1` and `decorator2` functions. And I am using these to decorate a function.

```
@decorator1("some", "args")
@decorator2(1,2)
@decorator1()
def my_func(): print("my func")
```

When I call wrapped functions iteratively over and over again, output becomes like this:

for `my_func.__wrapped__`:

```
decorator1
decorator2
decorator1
my func
```

for `my_func.__wrapped__.__wrapped__()`:

```
decorator2
decorator1
my func
```

Problem is every wrapped function's name is `my_func`. I want to check if a function in this chain is instance of lets say `decorator1`. I want to know this because I will use arguments of decorators. (I already know them by using `__closure__` cells.)

**Clarification**

I decided to give and example to show my purpose.

```
@route("/index")
def index(): pass

@route("/settings")
@need_permission("admin")
def settings: pass

@route("/blog")
@need_permission("admin", "user")
def blog(): pass
```

I can get all these route functions somewhere else, and I want to extract which one needs which permissions.

Here my findings:

```
>>> blog()
route blog
permissions admin user
>>> blog.__closure__[0].cell_contents
('/blog',)
>>> blog.__closure__[1].cell_contents()
permissions admin user
>>> blog.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__closure__[0].cell_contents
('admin', 'user')
>>> blog.__closure__[0].cell_contents.__closure__[1].cell_contents()
>>>
```

I just want to extract the tuples that hold permissions. I can apply my decorators in some specific order and extract easily or I need to implement my `DecoratorApplier` function as @Poolka pointed out. If there is no way of knowing like first option, i will follow second.

Comment: You need to provide more detail about the decorators. The `__wrapped__` attribute is added by something in the definition of the decorators, not something added just by the act of decorating a function.

Comment: Decorators aren't magic; it's just a shortcut for `def my_func():...; my_func = decorator1("some", "args")(decorator2(1,2)(decorator1()(my_func)))`.

Comment: Note that `__wrapped__` is probably added by `functools.wraps`, whose purpose is to make the wrapped function look as much like the function it wraps as possible. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper.

Comment: Yes I know how decorators work but I thought there may be another way. I also added a clarification.

Comment: @maydin I modified the answer slightly. Not sure if it's reasonable solution to the issue. Maybe there is another way to get that info somehow?

Answer (score 0):

`instance of a decorator` - decorators implemented with functions and regular functions are all just functions of type `function`.

Not sure what exactly you wanna get. The code below is how I would approach the problem. Basically I add attribute `primal_type` to all the functions involved into decoration carnival to store the name of the functions/decorators. I do this with another decorator named `DecoratorApplier`. The code seems to perform something related to the issue in the question.

**EDIT**

Added clarification didn't make everything clear. I guess it's not good practrice to mix function and decorator logics in that way. Maybe there is another option to get desired info inside the function? Anyway two modified versions of my original approach below (`oda` stands for optional decorator arguments).

(1) - with `DecoratorApplier`

```
import functools


def decorator_1(*d1_args, **d1_kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('inside decorator_1', d1_args, d1_kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


def decorator_2(*d2_args, **d2_kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('inside decorator_2', d2_args, d2_kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


class DecoratorApplier:

    def __init__(self, *decorators):
        self.decorators = decorators

    def __call__(self, func):
        func.oda = dict()
        for decorator in self.decorators:
            func = decorator[0](*decorator[1], **decorator[2])(func)
            (
                func
                .oda
                .setdefault(decorator[0].__name__, list())
                .extend([decorator[1], decorator[2]])
            )
        return func


@DecoratorApplier(
    (decorator_1, (1, 2), {'x': 10, 'y': 20}),
    (decorator_2, tuple(), dict()))
def f_1():
    print('inside f_1')
    print(f_1.oda)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    f_1()
```

(2) - with modifying original decorators

```
import functools


def decorator_1(*d1_args, **d1_kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('inside decorator_1', d1_args, d1_kwargs)
            (
                kwargs
                .setdefault('oda', dict())
                .setdefault('decorator_1', list())
                .extend([d1_args, d1_kwargs])
            )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


def decorator_2(*d2_args, **d2_kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('inside decorator_2', d2_args, d2_kwargs)
            (
                kwargs
                .setdefault('oda', dict())
                .setdefault('decorator_2', list())
                .extend([d2_args, d2_kwargs])
            )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator


@decorator_1(1, 2, x=10, y=20)
@decorator_2()
def f_1(oda=None):
    print('inside f_1')
    print('    oda', oda)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':

    f_1()
```